# pandas creating Dataframe with fixed dtypes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to create DataFrame where columns are both int and float type proper..

I'm trying to create a sample pandas dataFrame while testing as follows but when I see the `dtypes`  specilat in DataFrame `df1` for column `weight` it converts `int` 4 to float as it has the second value .15

So, i'm  not getting a way to create a column with mixed values like `4` as int  and `.15` as float.

```
$ df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Matrial':  ['gold', 'platnm'],  'weight': [4, .15]})
$ df1
  Matrial  weight
0    gold    4.00
1  platnm    0.15
```

While checking dtypes..

```
$ df1.dtypes
Matrial     object
weight     float64
dtype: object
```

It should looks like:

```
$ df1
  Matrial  weight
0    gold    4
1  platnm    .15
```

DataFrame df2 :

```
$ df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'ratio1':  [8, 10],  'ratio2': [4, 2]})
$ df2
   ratio1  ratio2
0       8       4
1      10       2
```

While checking dtypes..

```
$ df2.dtypes
ratio1    int64
ratio2    int64
dtype: object
```

Sorry, question may be looks silly but being a new learner to pandas i'm not getting it.

Comment: You can't, the columns of a pandas DataFrame / Series are homogeneously of type.

Comment: @Abhi, so how to convert that in a way that  `4.0` may become int as literal `4`  and `0.15` may `.15`?

Comment: You can't convert a float to an int.

Comment: yes, df1's weight to df2's both column if its  float then result will be altogether different which is in int

Comment: Your only option, if you **must** have the integer representation is to convert the entire column to an object type, which can be used as a container for multiple types. However, there really isn't any reason for this, and this should be avoided at all costs. You don't need to worry about precision, because small integers can be represented exactly with floats. Even with only 16 bits,`np.float16(4) == int(4)` evaluates to True. Using 64 bits you can represent enormous integers precisely.

Comment: @ALollz, an you set an example.